# Make a loop with cardinal spline

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make an animation for a sprite, which will go on path and it will loop forever. But CardinalSpline doesn't close up as I thought.

Here are example points (it's a square):

```
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 350));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 150));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(150, 150));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(150, 350));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 350));
```

Animation creation:

```
auto redSpline = CardinalSplineTo::create(20, pointsRed, 0);
```

It looks like that:

[image]

So of course animation doesn't look too good. I want to make a perfect loop (with constant speed), where cannot be seen where's an end or start.

If I will continue adding the same points it will loop nice until it reaches the end where's an breakdown, which you can see on top right corner.

How can I achieve this?

Only thing, which comes to my mind is too double amount of points and at exactly half of animation seek it to the begging or create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it. I had to change cocos2d-x code a bit.

All needed changes:

in startWithTarget:

```
_deltaT = (float) 1 / (_points->count() - 1);
```

to:

```
_deltaT = (float) 1 / (_points->count());
```

Reimplemented getControlPointAtIndex:

from:

```
Vec2 PointArray::getControlPointAtIndex(ssize_t index)
{
      index = MIN(static_cast<ssize_t>(_controlPoints->size())-1, MAX(index, 0));  
      return *(_controlPoints->at(index));
}
```

to:

```
Vec2 PointArray::getControlPointAtIndex(ssize_t index)
{
    ssize_t tIndex = index;
    ssize_t pSize = static_cast<ssize_t>(_controlPoints->size());
    if(tIndex < 0) tIndex += pSize;
    if(tIndex >= pSize) tIndex -= pSize;    
    return *(_controlPoints->at(tIndex));
}
```

Then spline is interpolating well, because it always has 4 different points to interpolate. Before that first and last point were cut off.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a spline in CAD programs such as AutoCAD, you must specify not only points, but also the direction (imaginary extension) for the extreme points. Direction affects the behavior of the spline from the extreme point to the next.
Here the direction is not specified, so the extreme point of the spline has a "sharp transition".
Try to add two points to indicate the direction, for example:

```
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(300, 360));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 350));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 150));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(150, 150));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(150, 350));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(350, 350));
pointsRed->addControlPoint(Vec2(360, 300));
```

I pointed out the approximate position of the extreme points. You should to move them and determine the exact position to achieve precise overlay of a spline.
P.S. Or you can try to connect the spline is not at the corner and on a flat plot of the spline, for example at the point (250, 360).

Comment: Please tell me how to make an object move in a certain path. I need to do it with Particle, so I enter a mathematical equation spiral in the scheduler with setPosition().

Comment: I tried your path and it doesn't work as expected. I think the problem is that function doesn't know that it should loop and properly connect last and first point. I've looked into cocos2d-x code and here's an interpolation between 4 points.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer concerned only spline creation. But now I made my particle rotation by spiral, and know the simplest way which can help you.
So, you need a container for your’s object, and you should make two things: rotate container and move object on container. I will show an example with particle as object:

```
Sprite* container = Sprite::create("background.png");
container->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ANCHOR_MIDDLE); // the container is rotated about its center 
container->setPosition(winSize.width * 0.5f, winSize.height * 0.5f);
container->setOpacity(255); // it’s only for test. After that you can setOpacity(0)
this->addChild(container);

ParticleSystemQuad* particle = ParticleSystemQuad::create("particle_meteor.plist");
// place object 100 pixels above the center of the container
particle->setPosition(container->getBoundingBox().size.width * 0.5f, container->getBoundingBox().size.height * 0.5f + 100);
container->addChild(particle);

container->runAction(RotateBy::create(4.0f, 360));

EaseInOut* easeUp = EaseInOut::create(MoveBy::create(0.4f, Vec2(0, 35)), 2.0f);
EaseInOut* easeDown = EaseInOut::create(MoveBy::create(0.4f, Vec2(0, -35)), 2.0f);
particle->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(0.1f),
                                     easeUp,
                                     easeDown,
                                     DelayTime::create(0.2f),
                                     easeUp,
                                     easeDown,
                                     DelayTime::create(0.2f),
                                     easeUp,
                                     easeDown,
                                     DelayTime::create(0.2f),
                                     easeUp,
                                     easeDown,
                                     DelayTime::create(0.1f),
                                     NULL)); // particle «jumps» in corners
```

Here I show only one turnover, but you can get it to rotate continuously. There is result of program:

[image]

It is not same as your splain, but the principle of the creation should be clear. I think, you can decrease the distance in `MoveBy:` and experiment with `Ease:` for a better results.

Comment: I see, but the problem is I just made simple example, where you can do move 4 times and voila. But in real case I have a lot more complicated path. But I just changed cocos2d-x code and achieved what I needed!

Comment: Great! Your decision has wider application. This time I had enough of my decision. But if I got the next time such a task - how do you attach the moving object to the spline's path?

Comment: What do you mean by attach? Spline path was just drawn line to show how it's looking. Now I'd have to modify drawing function as well to draw correct path.

Comment: I understand you need a spline in order to create a path along which to move the object. I could be wrong, English is not my native language. I am wondering how to make the object moving along the path, which is created using the spline.

Comment: I've created several nodes in Cocos Studio, which I read at startup. I just need their positions. Then I add them to one PointArray. I put on sprite at first point and run action on it: CardinalSplineTo::create(20, pointsRed, 0);